Due Date Task object not appearing in Quick Action not appearing
I am struggling here, I am trying to have my page layout with due date appear when creating a new task based off a custom quick action on Opp.

Its confirmed on the page layout, permission to it, etc etc
however it does not appear, but it does appear when creating a task from Tasks itself.

even when editing a task from the dropdown in activities pane, I can now see the due date:


Was due date added to the Quick Action? They have their own, separate layouts aside from the normal task layout.

SMH, thank you, working to fast. @sfdcfox

Quick Actions have their own, independent layout separate from the page layout for an object. You'll need add the field in the Action Layout Editor.
